# Unrelated edit rejection comments

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

[My suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18466657) 
 for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168712/threejs-boxhelper-scale-not-working) was recently rejected. I can handle rejection--it has happened before, and will surely happen again--but the reasons involved confuse me.

The details of my edit were:

- I corrected capitalization in the body of the question
- I added a snippet which incorporated the author's (*unedited*) code into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so others could see the problem in action (the result was broken just like how the author described).

My edit comment ("Added MCVE, fixed spelling.") may be the root of all this, but the rejection comments don't line up with that either.

I also described what I had done in a comment on the post, and suggested the author make further edits to include more information.

The edit was rejected 2-1, with the following rejection reasons:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Which is the "attempt to reply" rejection reason--clearly I was not attempting to answer the question. The author's code was copied into the example verbatim, with no attempt to edit or fix it. Further, I reserved my request for more information to my comment, not the edit.

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Which is the "clearly conflicts with author's intent" rejection reason. Again, I didn't alter the author's words, nor the code they provided. All I did was put it into an example which demonstrated the issue for which they were requesting assistance.

To sum it up, I really did very little in the edit, other than provide an example of the author's problem--not an answer--using the author's original code. Why then was the edit rejected for the reasons given, neither of which seem to relate to the actions I actually took?

Comment: So you've added *your own code* as OP's? (if I'm wrong - please clarify in the post)... Really not something that should be done (maybe except rare cases of popular useful abandoned question)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no, it's *much* more nuanced. OP just added boilerplate code that otherwise anyone trying to reproduce the problem would need to type, effectively saving man/hours of work to try to take a stab solving the question, since you don't have to get those. The code that OP added is basically the same the asker had, plus code needed so you could just copy-n-paste it into your favorite debugger (or in this case, not even that since it's warped into the StackSnippets).

Comment: @Braiam While I appreciate your support, Alexei does have a point. While my intention was exactly as you describe--to provide a working framework so the author's code could be easily run/tested--it was not entirely clear where the author's code lived in that framework, and I should have made a better effort to highlight that. But for the future, I won't be doing this kind of edit at all, as I can see how it raises too many questions. Instead I'll leave comments with links to resources on how the author can do it themselves, which is how it should be, really.

Comment: "I won't be doing this kind of edit at all," And that's what I feared. That a single setback and the hostile environment prevents anyone from improving the site.

Comment: @Braiam Let me clarify: I do not intend to do this kind of edit, meaning: **1.** Injecting a large amount of code (and I would only ever insert test harnesses anyway) without being clear where the author's code fits in, **2.** When it comes to large/complex edits, the more detail I can put in the edit comments, the better. I'm not giving up on making content better, I'm just going to try to be better about making that content better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a handful of predefined reasons for rejecting edits, and the option to write a custom one. Most folks just pick a canned reason, and thus it won't necessarily match the actual objection; you kinda have to read between the lines.

In this case, you wrote "Added MCVE" - but didn't explain how you obtained it. A bit of investigation suggests you wrapped the author's snippet into a test program sufficient to demonstrate the problem, but this is easy to overlook when reviewing the edit - at first glance, it appears that you added an entire program of your own to the author's question, which is a common mistake for folks who...

- ...intended to *answer* the question, or
- ...have their own tangentially-related problem and are trying to piggyback on someone else's question.

Both of which match the reasons for rejection.

Next time, I recommend doing one or both of the following:

1. Explain exactly what you're doing in the edit summary. Something like, "wrapped the asker's code in a snippet to allow it to be reproduced quickly"
2. Comment the code itself. Something like,

   ```js
   //
   // test harness for the code listed above
   //
   var renderer, scene, camera, controls, stats;
   ```

   ...

   ```js
   function populateScene() {
     // the problematic logic as shown above
     var sphere = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6, 20, 6);
     var object = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(0xff0000));
     var box = new THREE.BoxHelper(object, 0xffff00);
     var gui = new dat.GUI();
     gui.add(box.scale, 'x', 0, 50).name('Width').listen();
     // end problematic code

     scene.add(object);
     scene.add(box);
   }
   ```

   ...

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I agree I should have given a better edit comment, and done more to highlight where the author's code was versus the test environment. Personally, I wouldn't assume that any edit is trying to answer or nudge a question in a particular direction, but I'm still rather new here, so I'm probably just naive in that respect. I'll do better. Thanks again.